# How do I uninstall and remove Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, uninstall, restore

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 after creating a demo disk from an .iso file.  It offered to create a dual boot version where ubuntu coexists with my preinstalled windows XP from HP.  both systems work fine side by side.

Everything worked OK but after evaluating it I need to revert to my original configuration of Windows XP only. There does not appear to be any info on removing/uninstalling Ubuntu when one does not have a Microsoft XP OS disk... but has only a recovery disk on my main hard drive.

Can anyone suggest the steps that I need to follow or where I might find instructions?  I figure all we need to do is stop ubuntu from hijacking the boot process and then I could delete the partitions its on.

Many thanks.