# Remove Ubuntu From Computer or Laptop

Tags: uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I uninstall and remove Ubuntu 11.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98244/how-do-i-uninstall-and-remove-ubuntu-11-10)

I have a Laptop which uses Ubuntu as Operating System. Ubuntu is fine but it does not support such applications like Games, Softwares and Other Things which are badly needed. So, I Want to remove Ubuntu and Install Windows XP. So, Please Explain me the process of removal of Ubuntu. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are dual booting, just boot into Windows instead.

If you are not, you will need to (re-)install Windows.  Simply insert the Windows Installation CD, and follow the instructions.  Beyond that, this is an Ubuntu website, so we can't provide any help with the windows installation process.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply format the partitions where ubuntu is installed. Althoug what you say is not exactly true, there are alot of Games in Ubuntu, even the possibilty of playing Windows games in Ubuntu through CrossOver

Answer (score 0):

if you do not have any personal files in your `/home/` directories just boot from your Windows install medium and reinstall with the format option.

Hope to see you soon back at Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to uninstall Ubuntu to install other OS like windows.

Buy a valid copy of Windows, insert the CD, and restart your computer.

Before the Ubuntu starts to load, use your bios and start your computer from cd (or usb, may be)

Follow the steps. Windows Installer will ask you to format* your hdd. Don't forget to have your backups before you proceed.