# How can I remove Ubuntu from my system and install the Windows bootloader?

Tags: bootloader

I want to completely remove Ubuntu from my system. But if I delete the partition, the Grub files will be deleted and that will leave me "Bootloader-less". How can I workaround this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [http://askubuntu.com/questions/98244/how-do-i-uninstall-and-remove-ubuntu-11-10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/98244/how-do-i-uninstall-and-remove-ubuntu-11-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simpliest method I can think of:

1. Boot to Windows;
2. Download **mbrfix** from `http://download.cnet.com/MbrFix/3000-2094_4-10485990.html`;
3. Extract the package and copy **mbrfix.exe** to your favorite directory;
4. Open a command prompt as an administrator, navigate to your favorite directory (`cd`);
5. Enter the command: `mbrfix /drive 0 fixmbr` and confirm.
6. Reboot.

Now the Windows bootloader is back. You can mess up the Ubuntu partition at will.

Answer (score 1):

You can either boot into Windows (you seem to have an existing installation) and install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) (free for non-commercial use) to fix the bootloader, or boot with the Windows install disc, which gives you an option to repair the bootloader as well.

Answer (score 1):

## Removing Ubuntu and fixing the Windows bootloader

Boot up a live CD or USB and delete your Ubuntu (ext4 and swap) partitions using GParted. You can expand your Windows partitions at this point as well. Then, open up the terminal and use these commands:

- sudo apt-get install lilo
- sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr

When you reboot, you should boot straight into your Windows install.