# grub rescue error while uninstalling Ubuntu12.04

Tags: grub2, uninstall

I have xp and ubuntu . I unistall ubuntu using xp desktop by unallocating memory from memory management.

After that when i reboot my laptop i got grub rescue error.

so after reading some blogs i use my Xp CD recovery console and tried
**fixmbr
fixboot**

but this also not solve my problem . It still shows grub rescue on booting.
What should i do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MBR is screwed and you need to recover it. Please refer to this [How can I remove Ubuntu from my system and install the Windows bootloader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130849/how-can-i-remove-ubuntu-from-my-system-and-install-the-windows-bootloader)